# Identity Server Saml2AuthExtensions Idp initiated SSO handling the respose

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, sustainsys-saml2

This is a follow up question to [Identity Server Saml2AuthExtensions Idp initiated SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521457/identity-server-saml2authextensions-idp-initiated-sso)

We have got a client who wants to use Idp initiated SSO to login to our application. We have managed to get to a point where this is now authenticating the user, calling back to our Identity Server instance but I'm now struggling to actually login the user on our side.

I used our standard ExternalCallback method to handle the response, but unlike the SP initialed login when we use SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() to build the session ready to login it's returning null, and I'm not really sure why, or if this is even what your are supposed to handle the call coming back in

Just to add, a SP initiated login works fine

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've sort of worked out how to do this now. I've written a version of the GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() method that doesn't check for a provider in the returned items. This seems to work ok